# Autorefresh angular component

Tags: angular

I have a calendar layout, a cell for each day. I want to click on a cell, write on the db "vacation" for that day, return a response if succeded and the cell should appear with a different colour.

My problem is that the colour appears only when I refres the page and read from db... how can I make an autorefresh for the component?

I have a parent component that has all the data (user, state etc) and with it I am calling the service method and a child component that represents a month with its days.

here is what I did for this functionality in parent component :

```
 this.holidayClicked = function (day: CalendarMonthViewDay): Observable<boolean> {
        const username = this.user.userId;
        const holiday = new EmployeeHoliday();
        holiday.date = new Date(Date.UTC(day.date.getFullYear(), day.date.getMonth(), day.date.getDate()));
        holiday.state = that.stateSelected;
        holiday.comment = '';

        return this.calendarService.updateEmployee(username, holiday).map(
          _ => {
            if (holiday && holiday.state.stateVal !== 1) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          });
      };
```

and this is from my child component

```
@Input() holidayClicked: Function;

  dayClicked(day: CalendarMonthViewDay): void {
    const sub = this.holidayClicked(day);
    sub.subscribe(isHoliday => {
      if (isHoliday === true) {
        console.log('Huuuuoooooo');
      } else {
        console.log('Hooray!!!!!!');
      }
      this.refresh.next();
    });

public refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Comment: have you tried setIntervial in parent component for autorefresh

Comment: @celamoet A stackblitz will help us to see, where exactly the change detection is not triggering and why. From your example i don't see where you are setting the `color` for calendar dates ?

Comment: Are you getting 'Hooray' or 'Huuuuoooooo' logged on to the console?